# Injecting commands by sending keystrokes to a command windows?

Tags: c#, command-line, sendkeys

I have a command prompt window that runs a web based piece of software. I want to make a program in C# that injects commands into the running command prompt window.

Any pointers?

Thanks, Paul.

Comment: What are you mean under "injecting commands"? Do you intend to modify running app or just to send input to console?

Comment: Just send input to the console.

Answer (score 8):

Quick and dirty method:

use [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the focus to the cmd window, then use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send keystrokes to the cmd window.

You can use [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/sendinput.html) P/Invoke definition to call SendInput from c#:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);
```

and [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setfocus) one for SetFocus

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);
```

In order to get the window handle that you required for SetFocus, you can use [FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/findwindow.html)  or perhaps get the appropriate cmd process using `Process.GetProcessesByName` and then use the `MainWindowHandle` property.